# Xephyr on Ubuntu 14.04 via SSH is buggy?

Tags: ssh

I tried Xephyr on Ubuntu 12.04.4 via SSH(putty+Xming) X-forwarding running WM(fluxbox, XFCE4), which runs well.

However, with Ubuntu 14.04 (server), Xephyr got "Caught signal 11" and quit on the test as below

```
Xephyr -ac -screen 800x600 -reset :1 &
```

Since currently the version number of Xephyr is 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2, which it is completely different from 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10 which runs on Ubuntu 12.04, so I don't have other option to downgrade.

Anyone had the similar issue with Xephyr on 14.04 LTS? Or just me.. Any comment is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-noxv`.

If this does not help, please post the full error if you have more.